# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys { my keys })

Tags: json, react-native

when I submit my form with the const onSubmit, I fetch data. If the submit form is ok, I want to extract the data I get from my api. So I use, setState reponse : my data, and then I want to pass this data (reponse) to the component SingleLayout.

But it doesn't work. I get this error : *[Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {ID, Post Title, post_date, Prix, Surface, Ville, Category, featured_image, mandats_signes, date_de_signature_du_compromis}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.]*

Here the code :

```
export default class QueryChild extends Component {

  state = {
    username: "",
    password: "",
    isLogged: null,
    email: "",
    reponse: '',
    id: 4577
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.render();


  }


  onSubmit = async() => { 
    const fetchValue = 'myAPI/suivi-dossier?' + 'username=' + this.state.username + '&password=' + this.state.password + '&id=' + this.state.id
    try {

        await fetch(fetchValue, {
            method: 'GET'
            
          })
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((responseJson) => {
              if(responseJson.success === true) {
                // I want to extract this : 
                this.setState({ reponse: responseJson.message })

                this.setState({ isLogged: true })


              } else {
                this.setState({reponse : responseJson.message });
                console.log(this.state.reponse)
              }
            
            // this.setState({
            //    data: responseJson
            // })
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
          });

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }

  }


    render() {

      if(this.state.isLogged === true) {
        // when user is Logged, I want to pass this.state.reponse to my component SingleLayout
        // but I get the error : [Error: Objects are not valid as a React child 
        // (found: object with keys {ID, Post Title, post_date, Prix, Surface, Ville, 
        // Category, featured_image, mandats_signes, date_de_signature_du_compromis}). If you 
        // meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.]

        const SingleComponent = this.state.reponse.map(message => <SingleLayout key={message.ID} table={message}/> )
        

      
      return (
    <SafeAreaView>
          {SingleComponent}
    </SafeAreaView>
      );
      } else {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <ScrollView>
                <ImageBackground source={image} resizeMode="cover" style={styles.image}>
                        <Spacer taille={70} />
                        <View style={styles.content}>
                            <Image
                            style={styles.imgLogo}
                            source={require('../../logo.png')}
                            />
                           
                            <Text style={styles.logo}>Pour des raisons de sécurité, veuillez entrer vos Identifiants</Text>
                            <View style={styles.inputContainer}>

                                <Text style={styles.textBasique}>{this.state.reponse}</Text>

                                <TextInput 
                                placeholder='Identifiant ou adresse email'
                                style={styles.input}
                                value={this.state.username}
                                onChangeText={val => this.setState({ username: val})}
                                />

                                <TextInput 
                                placeholder='Mot de passe'
                                style={styles.input}
                                value={this.state.password}
                                secureTextEntry= {true}
                                onChangeText={val => this.setState({ password: val})}
                                />


                                <Spacer taille={10} />
                                <Button title='Se Connecter' onPress={this.onSubmit}/>
                                <Spacer taille={10} />

                            </View>
                        </View>
                        <Spacer taille={200} />
                    </ImageBackground>
                </ScrollView>
        </View>
        )
      }
      }
    
      
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO I finally solved my problem :

the code i change :

QueryChild.tsx :

```
  if(responseJson.success === true) {
    //here : 
    this.setState({ reponse: JSON.stringify(responseJson.message) }) 

    this.setState({ isLogged: true })
```

and I directly return SingleLayout like that :

```
  return (
      <SafeAreaView>
          <SingleLayout table={this.state.reponse} />  
      </SafeAreaView>
```

Now I can access this.state.reponse into my SingleLayout :

```
const SingleLayout = (props) => {
    let id = props.id
    let table = props.table

    const myObj = JSON.parse(table);
    
    console.log(myObj[0].mandats_signes)
    console.log(myObj[0].ID)
    console.log(myObj[0].Category)
    //etc...

    const { colors } = useTheme();


        return (
            <View style={[styles.container, {backgroundColor: colors.background}]}>
                <Text>Bravo</Text>
            </View>
        )
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The response that comes from the server is an object. Since the "map" function only works with an array so, if you want to run this code you've to wrap "responseJson.message" into the array.

```
if(responseJson.success === true) {
     this.setState({ reponse: [responseJson.message] }) 
     this.setState({ isLogged: true })  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes I get similar error after applying the solution because I found that the error comes from the setState reponse. So I added JSON.stringify and now the error is gone.

The code of Single Layout :

```
const SingleLayout = (props) => {
    let id = props.id
    let table = props.table
    
    console.log(table)

    const { colors } = useTheme();


        return (
            <View style={[styles.container, {backgroundColor: colors.background}]}>
                <Text>Bravo</Text>
            </View>
        )
}
```

Now with the solution : const SingleComponent = Object.keys(this.state.reponse).map(key =>  )

it works but it send caracters one by one

Answer (score 0):

it's not a good practice to pass JSON and then parse.

I solved it and here is the link with the same solution that I presented to you:
https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-bouman-qyi5y?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Well thank you ! I implement this ! and why it is not a good pratice ?

Comment: @RomainPlantureux because you're already converting it into an object when you are getting it from API. 

Follow this article referring to bad practice:
https://medium.com/@pmzubar/why-json-parse-json-stringify-is-a-bad-practice-to-clone-an-object-in-javascript-b28ac5e36521

If you find my solution useful kindly approve and upvote it.